# What is the "useful" range of a 4 byte float?

Tags: floating-point, x86

Lets say I had a function `f(x) = x * 10 ^ -N`

In this case, what would be the biggest N as long as

`f(1) < f(2)`

`f(2) < f(3)`

etc up to  x=10  as long as the result was between -1 and 1

after the result gets stored in a 4 byte float?

For instance, I know that N = 50 is unacceptable because after being stored in a 4 byte float, any number up to 10 turns into 0.

Also what is the biggest N where the result is still lets say 90% accurate?

EDIT: Hardware in question: x86 based modern processor

EDIT2: Meanwhile, I created this simple thing to bruteforce test for the accuracy it:

```
int main() {

    double dbl;
    float sng;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        double increment = std::pow(10, -i);

        dbl = 0;
        while (dbl < 1) {
            dbl += increment;
            sng = dbl;

            double check = (double)sng / dbl;
            if (check != 1) {
                if (check < 0.9 || check > 1.11111) {
                    std::cout << "Fail at N = " << i;
                    goto stop;
                }

            }

        }
        std::cout << "Checked " << i << "\n";
    }

    stop:

    return 1;
}
```

Its been stuck at N = 9 for a while now.. could finish any second now or a thousand years later...

Comment: Which hardware are you asking about? Not all hardware platforms use the same floating point format.

Comment: I assume IEEE-754 single-precision is used for `float` since you say the system is an x86 processor. If I understand your specification correctly, the largest N that fulfills the requirements is 44 if denormals are supported, 38 if denormals are not supported (that is, the FPU operates in flush-to-zero mode). Depending on your compiler, you may need a compiler switch such as `/fp:strict` to turn on denormal support.

Comment: dang! thats more than I expected, my program is at N=10 now.. think I might as well shut it off.

Comment: @njuffa How did you arrive at those numbers? Would you mind providing a quick explanation (comment or answer as you prefer)

Comment: @Basic Smallest IEEE-754 `binary32` denormal: 2**-149 ~= 10**-44.85. Smallest IEEE-754 `binary32` normal: 2**-126 ~= 10**-37.93